# EditText and MultiAutoCompleteTextView suggestions

Tags: android, autocomplete, android-edittext

I'm using a MultiAutoCompleteTextView in my app to show various suggestions.

I noticed that MultiAutoCompleteTextView doesn't support the regular android suggerstion that come defaultly with an EditText (the strip of suggestions that pops above the soft keyboard.

Is there a way of showing both the regular suggestions, and the ones I want to show in my MultiAutoCompleteTextView?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found that setting the input types only took effect when I set them with `setRawInputType()`. I also found out that the only way to use `InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_CORRECT` was to include 
include `InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT` also. So it would result in something like this:

```
multiAutoCompleteTextView.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT
  |InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES
  |InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_CORRECT
  |InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
```